# Dependencies description of wxWidgets libraries

Tags: wxwidgets, codeblocks, windows-7-x64

I simply want to use wxRichTextCtrl, but I have dependencies, dependencies, dependencies...
So, **libwxmsw30u_richtext.a** has this dependencies:
libwxmsw30u_html.a, libwxbase30u_xml.a, libwxexpat.a and more more more.

Is somewhere FAQ about such dependencies?

Because I have one unsolved dependency on "wxToolbook, wxChoiceBook" by now, and I have no idea what library I miss. I feel that is not last dependency I will need to solve to start using wxRichTextCtrl.

Comment: You could link all the libraries (`*w30u_*.a`) , the linker *should* simply discard any library that is not actually used.  Also, once you have done a successful link, the linker map should show which `.a` files were used.

Comment: To find which library has a particular symbol, `grep wxToolbook *.a`  (there will be some false positives but that will help narrow it down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of each class mentions the library it is defined in, e.g. [wxToolbook documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_toolbook.html) says that it is in wxCore library and, BTW, clicking on this library brings you to the library list page mentioned in @catalin's answer above which also lists [wxRichText library dependencies](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/page_libs.html#page_libs_wxrichtext).

The advice to just link with everything if you're not sure is sound as well, BTW, the unused libraries will simply be discarded.

Comment: I still can't link project in C::B. I have this libraries in build options - http://pastebin.com/yHtk5WfW in this order. And I have no idea, how to use wildcard, I got **library -l*.a not found**

Comment: It's impossible to say what the problem is without knowing the error you get, but two general points: first, you can't use wildcards with the linker no more than you can use them with the compiler. Second, the order of static libraries *matters*. You must put the library containing the dependencies of another one *after* it.

Answer (score 0):

See the [wxWidgets Library List](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/page_libs.html).

However it does not include 3rd party libs like wxexpat, wxzlib, wxjpeg etc.